# Segfaults from command line but works from GDB run

Tags: gdb

I'm really lost in here. Maybe some of you can point me to a right direction.

I'm developing a tool in ANSI C using GCC over MinGW. The tool is to be run only from command line. Probably only on windows machine. It elaborates some data locally and generates files for use by other programs. Basically it does a lot of math and a few file handling. Nothing really fancy. I didn't find it necessary posting the whole 1000+ lines here for examination...

I compile it with GCC `-ansi` making sure not even a single warning is present. Everything worked always well as the development evolved. But recently I started getting (almost) random segfaults. I checked for the last changes made, but found nothing. I removed the last changes completely coming back to when it perfectly worked. Still segfaults. I traced line by line. I went back to read and re-read the whole code searching for possible pointers/malloc errors. I simply can't find the reason for it to fail so often and so randomly.

So here is the strange thing - I compiled it with -g and run through GDB.

```
start MSYS
change dir where the program resides
$ gdb generatore.exe (the one compiled -g that fails)
$ run
```

And it perfectly works inside GDB. I went step by step. Line by line. Perfect. I tried stressing it with huge amounts of data. All works. Can't reproduce the error. But if the same executable is run from command line, it fails.

I suspect an unpredictable behavior with some pointer but I cannot find it anywhere.

Has anyone ever encountered anything similar? Where should I be checking? Also, I am not as familiar with GDB, since it runs smoothly, can I enforce the control somehow to find the reason it fails? Are any other free debugging solutions for windows you can advise me? How can I debug for unpredictable behaviors?

Thanks a lot for your attention,
maxim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a great free tool for catching all kind of runtime errors to do with pointers, memory allocations, deallocations, etc., which cannot be caught at compile time, so your compiler will not warn you about them: valgrind http://valgrind.org/. The problem is, AFAIK it doesn't run on Windows. However, if your program is pure ANSI C you should be able to build it and run it with valgrind on a Linux box.

I'm not 100% sure about it, but it should run OK in a virtual machine, so if you don't have a separate Linux computer you can try installing e.g. Ubuntu in Virtual Box or VmWare and try running your program with valgrind in it.

Comment: Thanks piokuc. I've read about valgrind being a great tool, but it will take me a little time to set a linux environment here. Definitely my next move. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user1885558 I know, it looks like a lot of effort to install a Linux, but it's worth it, it's good to have one around. You won't regret it :)

Comment: Got Amazon AWS account where I run Valgrind. Found ~40mb of leaking memory... Fixed that. Now ots stable on both systems. I realize over and over again, you go nowhere without a Linux on your side. Thanks, piokuc!

Comment: @MAXIM great! Linux rulez! :)